# Не работает scrollTop

Tags: jquery

Не могу программно прокрутить див вниз. При добавлении значения textarea див прокручивается, но если я  вручную прокручу этот див вверх, при следующем добавлении скролл не будет работать  как надо. Как мне учесть пользовательскую  прокрутку?

```
$(function (){
    $('button').click( function(){
        $('div').append("<p>" + $(this).prev().val() + "</p>");
        $('div').scrollTop($('div').height() + $('div').scrollTop());
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DkZc/3/

Comment: А нельзя просто аргументом для scrollTop взять, к примеру, 10000? Тогда всё работает.

Comment: это уже костыль.

Comment: @eicto, doesn't work for me(chrome). Прокрутите вверх и увидите - скролл вниз не опускается

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5DkZc/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея с суммированием высоты блока и текущей позиции прокрутки непонятна, чтобы скроллить до конца вниз надо [`scrollHeigh`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight) использовать:

```
$(function (){
    $div=$('div').first();
    $('button').click( function(){
        $div.append($("<p>").text($(this).prev().val()));
        $div.scrollTop($div.prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
});
```

Comment: проверяю ваш пример - он не работает

Comment: просто не работает ? http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/5DkZc/7/ вот здесь

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: поправил, видимо не тот фидл записал/скопировал

Comment: Вариант №7 работает на моём FF.

Comment: Признаюсь, не сталкивался с методом prop. scrollHeight нет в свойствах jQuery, поэтому это и сбило с толку. Всем спасибо!

Comment: это из DOM не метод а свойство

Comment: @eicto, какое же это свойство?

Comment: @eicto, я имел в виду,что prop - это метод, а scrollHeight - свойство